# Ruby counterpart of Lua _ variable name

Tags: ruby, variables, idioms

When fiddling with `redis` gem I found `#multi` and `#pipelined` methods, which allow grouping operations, whose results are later returned as an array.

```
getresult, delresult = redis.multi do
  redis.get key
  redis.del key
end
```

I'd like to store `getresult`, and omit `delresult`. In Lua typical practice is to use `_` as variable name for dropped values. Is there similar idiom in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same. You use `_` for ignored variables.

```
getresult, _ = redis.multi do
  redis.get key
  redis.del key
end
```

Comment: Huh, that was unexpected. I'm working with ruby and rails for 3 years now, and have never seen such construction :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_` to ignore one param or `*` any number of them

```
 def test(_);end
 test(1,2) #=> wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
 def test(*);end 
 test(1,2,3,4) #=> works fine
```

Same works for assignment.

Comment: Works for me in 1.9.3p194, ree-1.8.7-2011.03, jruby-1.6.5 and ruby head. The behavior of `*` would be the same as `_` in this case, because of mass assignment rules.

Comment: Ahh, it was matter of space between `*` and `=`